# Suppose $f(x)$ is two-times differentiable, $f(x),\;f'(x),\;f''(x)$ are all $>0$ and there are $a,\,b>0$ such that $f''(x)\leq af(x)+bf'(x)$

Tags: analysis

> Suppose $f(x)$ is two-times differentiable in $\mathbb R$, $f(x),\;f'(x),\;f''(x)$ are all $>0$ and there are $a,\,b>0$ such that 
>   $$
> f''(x)\leq af(x)+bf'(x),\qquad\text{for all $x\in\mathbb R$}.
> $$
>   Show that
>
> (1) $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)=0$.
>
> (2) There is a constant $c$ such that $f'(x)\leq cf(x)$.
>
> (3) Find the smallest $c$ in (2).

It's easy to prove (1), since otherwise $f(x)$ will not keep greater than zero.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3391545/prove-that-fx-y0-quad-text-for-all-x-y-in-mathbb-r2?noredirect=1   This is a question you asked before, but I don't quite understand the meaning of the prompt. Can you tell me something, thank you